# How to use custom language for compute() in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

`Compute()` with diff computer() output Error info in *different language*, but just need *English* output

.net core console 
VS2019(En and chinese)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Compute("1/0", "false");
```

some place output: `正无穷大`

some place output: `∞`

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");

dt.Locale = ci;
```

not work on `"zh-CN"` base computer, still output：`∞`

Comment: You should modify `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, e.g. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN");` not `dt.Locale`

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko That's seems not work